# Exposing wordpress media files to visitors

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a page on my wordpress site showing documents uploaded through the media library (ideally only specific files such as pdf, docx etc not images files). The idea is to have visitors directly download such files without logging in.

Any ideas on how to go about it ?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that will be best implemented through a Wordpress plugin. Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-assistant/

At the end of the day, if you can't find a pre-existing plugin, your best option is to make one. Some links for plugin development are:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Resources